# Netbeans 8.0.2, Glassfish 3 tutorial - where is the EAR file?

Tags: web-deployment, glassfish-3, ear, netbeans-8

I'm taking the following tutorial on creating an enterprise app through NetBeans:

```
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.html#Exercise_10
```

Before doing the tutorial, I downloaded Glassfish 3 (which we use in production) and added it as a server in NetBeans. I also deleted the Glassfish 4 server from the server node in the NetBeans IDE.

I've built, deployed and run the enterprise app - it works. However, the deployment instructions shown below suggest that an EAR file should have been created, and I haven't been able to find it. Where should I look, or was it actually created?

```
 Deploying the Enterprise Application
You can now build and run the enterprise application. When you run the application, the IDE will deploy the EAR archive to the server.
Right-click the EntAppEJB enterprise application and choose Deploy.
When you click Deploy, the IDE builds the enterprise application and deploys the EAR archive to the server. If you look in the Files window you can see that the EJBRemoteInterface JAR is deployed with the application.
In the Services window, if you expand the Applications node of GlassFish Server you can see that EntAppEJB was deployed.
```

Answer (score 1):

for me after clean build `EnterpriseApplication` i can find `.ear` under dist folder.